# Close Window using javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I need to close the window on click of a link. I can get it done through window.close() in IE but unable to do the same in Firefox. While googling, I found I have to set the

`dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` property to true to take effect in firefox as well.

Can someone guide me, how and where to set this property to true? I have no idea regarding that.

Comment: That looks like a firefox config param from about:config.  You can't force users to set it...

Answer (score 0):

You can only close child windows in firefox using javascript. Are you trying to close parent window ?

Comment: window.open('', '_self', ''); //bug fix
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")!=-1)
    {netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserWrite');}
    window.close();

Comment: Read this doc
http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-close.phtml 
and try this example http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/window-popup/javascript-window-close-example1.html

Comment: i know this stuff
but the problem i am facing is that the window I am trying to close is not opened through javascript.
and from some documents I have come to know that in firefox we cannot close a window which has not been opened through javascript

Answer (score 0):

On URL, you can type:

1. `about:config` and press enter.
2. Accept terms in second window.
3. You will get list of config entries in that search `dom.allow` and make it true by double clicking on value column.